# Accessing Image File from Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, webforms

I am trying to display an image from a Virtual Directory that is within my website. If I use the follwoing code the image is displayed on the Page:

```
Dim sourcefile As String = Server.MapPath("~/Common/Images/Flag.jpg")
Response.WriteFile(sourcefile)
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
```

But if I try displaying the image in an Image control useing the following code the image isn't displayed:

```
Dim sourcefile As String = Server.MapPath("~/Common/Images/Flag.jpg")
Image1.ImageUrl = sourcefile
```

Here is the HTML/ASP code:

```
    <div id="contentQE">
        <fieldset>
            <span class="graytitle">The Flag Image
                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            </span>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Server.MapPath will get the physical path to the file, which won't help the user accessing the site from the browser.

We usually do:

```
Dim sourcefile As String = Request.ApplicationPath & "/Common/Images/Flag.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image still isn't being displayed

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) Does that file exist already? 2) When you look at the source of the page, does the image path appear to be correct?

Comment: Question 1 - Yes, it is the same file that my first example is using. Question 2 - Yes.

Comment: Here is how the url is being rendered: <img id="Image1" src="/WebSiteName/Common/Images/Flag.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />

Comment: Have you tried just `Dim sourcefile As String = "~/Common/Images/Flag.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the bind method from the Image control, I have not test it yet, but I think It works.

Dim sourcefile As String = Server.MapPath("~/Common/Images/Flag.jpg")

Image1.ImageUrl = sourcefile

Image1.Bind()

Comment: Thanks but apparently the Bind method is not part of the Image object.

Comment: Sorry I meant DataBind() method.

Comment: Thanks again, but still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

[ASP.NET Web Project Paths From Microsoft Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)